# Qgis Interpolation TIN from srtm

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I'm new in qgis and I'm trying to realize a DEM from contour follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lzd5m0j3zTI&t=81s

My data came from seven SRTM frame downloaded with plugin in qgis, but after create the contours with gdal, the interpolation never goes well and in the option after click 'set to current extent' the cell size is 0,02. The SR of the project and of the contour lines is wgs84_4326, maybe it is a problem?

Comment: Based on the X/Y values in that video tutorial, it seems their contour layer uses meters or feet as its units, not decimal degrees. Try reprojecting the contour lines to an appropriate projected system.

Comment: When you reproject, be sure that you are actually reprojecting (right click on layer name in layer panel > save as > save with a different crs), not changing the projection in the layer properties.